# Delay Async Replication Time ClusterSet

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

I have following setup:

- Primary InnoDB Cluster with 3 instances(following Group Replication Protocol), R/W setting.
- Replica InnoDB Cluster with 3 instances(following Group Replication Protocol), R/O setting.

The Primary Cluster and Replica Clusters follow Async Replication Protocol.

I want to delay the async replication from primary to replica cluster.

I am not able to find any variable or setting to do so.

**Please note:** The primary and replica are InnoDB Clusters.